# QuickLook with IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, quicklook, ikimagebrowserview

I know IKImageBrowserView can be set to take control of the QuickLook panel, but how can I show that panel programmatically?

Thank you

Comment: Truth to be told, I'm able to show that panel using this trick: I set the browser as the first responder and then I simulate the keystroke of the spacebar. Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: a bit hackisch.. and what if space isnt configured to show QL -> a custom view can ignore it/ have another key for it odor.. the user could change it or apple could in 10.9 .. no emulating key presses isn't so cool IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ik.window makeFirstResponder:ik];
QLPreviewPanel *panel = [QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel];
[panel updateController];
[panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: that works for any view that can act as a dataSource for the panel

Comment: EXTREMELY USEFUL, nothing more to be said. Great!

Comment: If I close the panel before updating its controller (adding an instruction to your code) I effectively get a "toggle" behavior (which is what I want). Is this the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `-[IKImageBrowserItem imageRepresentationType]` returns `IKImageBrowserNSURLRepresentationType` or `IKImageBrowserPathRepresentationType`, all you have to do is set 
`-[IKImageBrowserView setCanControlQuickLookPanel:YES]` 
and then you will have QuickLook support.

However if the dataSoure return item is neither URLs or paths, you must also implement the `QLPreviewItem` protocol in your `IKImageBrowserView` subclass and return the requested URL for the custom cell.

See: [IKImageBrowserView class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html) for more detailed info

Comment: I would love to know why this solution which is stated clearly in the IKImageBrowerView class reference does not work for you.

Comment: That's not what I was asking: when I said "I know IKImageBrowserView can be set to take control of the QuickLook panel" I meant I was already doing what you wrote. And in fact what you wrote is completely different from the answer I accepted.